# Printf or Sprintf Statement in Perl

Tags: perl, printf

In Perl Print Statement or writing into a file, what does `"%%%%s"` mean?

```
("%%%s\n", $Fort)
```

Comment: The `%%` tells printf to print a single `%` character. The following `%s` tells printf to print `$Form` as a string. And the first line of your post is inconsistent with the second line. I believe the first line incorrectly cites the second one. But that's up to *you* to fix. I cannot do so without accidentally misinterpreting what you mean. You also have a `"` character that I think is not supposed to be there. You'll want to fix that too.

Answer (score 3):

Because % has special meaning within printf and sprintf templates, a means exists for including a % character in the output. That is accomplished by escaping the % with a %, so %% means print a % character.

And %s is the template for embedding a string. So these are two constructs. The first %% means output (or return) a % character, and the %s means embed a string, provided in the $Fort variable within your example.

This is documented in [perldoc -f sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf)